# Is it possible to create an order only if payment is completed?

Tags: checkout

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and i want to modify one of my payment methods. When this specific method is selected and the user clicks on `Complete Order` they are redirected on another website where they are able to make their payment. When the payment is done, the payment processor a.k.a the website where they pay sends us back a confirmation so we can know the payment is done.

Only when this payment is selected i want to force magento to NOT create an order until payment is confirmed.

Simple as that:
How can i make magento to create an order only when i receive a confirmation of payment? Is it possible?

I am asking for suggestions any information from where i can start will be very nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That isn't how magento works. The correct way to implement something like this would be to have it create the order right away, but the order invoice is not marked as collected until the payment is confirmed.

Comment: Is it a good solution to try this: When this specific payment method is used orders will receive a specific order status. The orders with status will be hidden everywhere in the admin and the frontend. When the payment is confirmed the order status will be changed ? How does it sounds to you, will it do the job ?